# Java is not using the decimals

Tags: java, decimal

So I am writing a program in which I am using a Double, but java is not using the decimal point. For example:

I have

double F;

F = 9/5;

Instead of java giving me 1.8 as an answer, it is just giving me back 1.0

Thanks for all the help

Comment: You need to have 9.0/5.0 because java only outputs integers for math on integers.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
F = (double)9/5;
```

because `9/5` will give int which then converted to double giving you `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
F = 9/5;
```

Java performs the integer division of `9` and `5`, which is `1`. Because the destination variable `F` is a `float`, Java converts the `1` into the equivalent `1.0`. If you want it to perform a floating-point division, use `9.0/5`. That way, the `5` is promoted to the equivalent `5.0`, and the division is thus `9.0/5.0=1.8`.